# Weird values on my vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, sdl

I have a method who put some content on my vector, that work with no problem. After that I want to reuse the content on my vector in another part of the program, but the problem is the values are not he good. But I don't know where I miss something

Here is some part of the code

The class where I do the stuff

```
class MapGenerator
{

public:
    void fillBoard(string level);
    void renderBoard();
    void initTileset();
    MapGenerator();
    ~MapGenerator();
    vector<Tile*> getTiles();

private:
    char     **board;
    int w;
    int h;
    int tileW;
    int tileH;
    vector<Tile*> tiles;

};
```

It's on the initTileset I put some stuff on my tiles vector.

After that on another part of my programe I call `renderBoard()` And there is the problem, I already have the good number of element on my vector but the values are not the good...

Here is the method, maybe my way to itterate is not correct :

Where I put the content on vector

```
void MapGenerator::initTileset()
{
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile("ressources/xml/tiles.xml");
    XMLElement* first = doc.FirstChildElement();

    for (XMLElement* child = first->FirstChildElement("tile"); child != NULL; child = child->NextSiblingElement())
    {
      string texture = child->FirstChildElement( "texture")->GetText();
      int x =  atoi(child->FirstChildElement("x")->GetText());
      int y =  atoi(child->FirstChildElement("y")->GetText());
      int w =  atoi(child->FirstChildElement("w")->GetText());
      int h =  atoi(child->FirstChildElement("h")->GetText());
      bool solid = false;
      if (atoi(child->FirstChildElement("solid")->GetText() ) == 1)
        solid =true; 
      char id = child->FirstChildElement("id")->GetText()[0];
      cout << "ID " << id << endl; 
      cout << "create tile : w " << w << " h " << h << endl;
      Tile tile(texture.c_str(), x, y, w, h, solid, id);
      cout << "Tile ID " << tile.getId()<< endl; 

      this->tiles.push_back(&tile);
    }
      cout << tiles.size() << endl;
     // renderBoard();
}
```

Where I try to reuse my vector

```
void MapGenerator::renderBoard()
{   
    SDL_Rect rect;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < w; j++)
        {
            vector<Tile *>::iterator it;
            for(it = tiles.begin(); it != tiles.end(); ++it) {
                cout <<  " ID :"  << (*it)->getId()  << " h " <<(*it)->getRect().h << " w " << (*it)->getRect().w << endl; 
                if ((*it)->getId() == board[i][j])
                {
                    rect.x = 32 * j;
                    rect.y = 32 * i;
                    rect.h = 32;
                    rect.w = 32;
                    SDL_RenderCopy( GameEngine::getInstance().getRenderer(), (*it)->getTexture(), NULL, &rect );
                     cout << " copy something y = " << i * 32<< " x = " << j *32<< " h " <<(*it)->getRect().h << " w " << (*it)->getRect().w <<endl;
                }
             }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

So someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you store pointers to a local variable in the vector. Once the `for` loop in the `initTileset` function iterates the `tile` variable goes out of scope and is destructed.

You need to allocate it on the heap:

```
Tile* tile = new Tile(texture.c_str(), x, y, w, h, solid, id);
```

You should of course not forget to free the allocated memory in the `MapGenerator` destructor.

Comment: Instead of using raw pointer, you can use some smart pointer, like shared_ptr<Tile>. But don't use auto_ptr. ;]